# Static assert on size of static const member

Tags: c++11, constexpr, static-assert

I'm trying to put a static assert on the size of static const unordered_map member. But I get an error saying non-const condition for static assertion. Could someone help?

```
#include<unordered_map>
#include<string>

using namespace std;    

class A{
    public:
    static const unordered_map<string,string> strMap;
};

const unordered_map<string,string> A::strMap ={{"key","value"}};

int main() {
static_assert(A::strMap.size() == 1, "sizes don't match");
}
```

EDIT: Based on the comments, I want to clarify, the following code works fine (it uses an array instead of a map):

```
#include<unordered_map>
#include<string>

using namespace std;    

class A{
    public:
    static const pair<string,string> strMap[];
};

const pair<string,string> A::strMap[] ={{"key","value"}};

int main() {
//static_assert(sizeof(A::strMap)/sizeof(A::strMap[0]) == 2, "sizes don't match");  Fails to compile
static_assert(sizeof(A::strMap)/sizeof(A::strMap[0]) == 1, "sizes don't match"); //Compiles fine
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't do this. You'd need `constexpr` std::unordered_map for this, and this is not possible, since it's constructor is not constexpr. And of course, no class which allocates memory (`unordered_map` being of this kind) can declare it's constructor constexpr.

Comment: Why is it possible with arrays, but not maps? I understand that arrarys don't have constructors, but I could have used an array of pair<string,string> and it'd have worked..

Comment: Because neither arrays, nor pairs allocate memory - so their constructors could be declared `constexpr`. Obviously, built-in arrays have no constructors per se - but they are still constexpr implicitly.

Comment: @user2308211 You can have constexpr arrays and pairs, but they can't contain `std::string`. So an array of pair<string,string> wouldn't work.

Comment: @interjay - for the same reason, as `std::string` allocates memory. I envision that at some point we will have a thriving ecosystems of constexpr containers - strings, maps, you name it. Would be fun.

Comment: @user2308211, what is the question? Size of arrays is always known at compile time, so it can be used in static_assert. Size of the map can not be known at compile time unless you call a constexpr-qualified member of the map class. And you can't do this, because the map constructor itself is not constexpr.